# How to write single update statement to update 3000 rows

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find a solution to write the best way to `update` 3000 records i.e

```
Update <table> set column1 = 'abc' where column2 = 'a.com'
Update <table> set column1 = 'def' where column2 = 'b.com'
Update <table> set column1 = 'cze' where column2 = 'c.com'
```

Similarly, I have to `update` 3000 rows.

How to write a better query? I raised this question earlier but didn't get a proper solution.

The values for column1 is coming from an excel which was populated from a different system. I don't have any other table to use `JOIN`. It is like a hard-coded value. currently, I manually generate the `update` statement for all 3000 in excel and try to execute it.

As I have to give it to the release management team to release it to production and they can't use excel to import, I have to provide a script to update these statements.

Do I need to split this 3000 `update` statement into batches or is there a better way?

My solution based on the replies:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PersonEmail

CREATE TABLE #PersonEmail 
(
    [Email] VARCHAR(100),
    [PersonId] VARCHAR(100)
)
    
INSERT INTO #PersonEmail ([Email], [PersonId])      
VALUES ('a.com', '100357'),
       ('b.com', '100358'),

UPDATE U
SET U.PersonId = PE.PersonId
FROM [dbo].[User] U
INNER JOIN #PersonEmail PE ON U.Email = PE.Email
```

Can anyone please confirm if this is correct?

Thanks

Comment: Use a `JOIN` (to a table type parameter/variable).

Comment: Hi @Larnu, I have updated my question. I dont have any table to JOIN. the values are coming from excel file.

Comment: Which is why I said (in parentheses) "to a table type parameter/variable." Pass the new data in a table type parameter and you can `JOIN` to that.

Comment: Update your excel with <column1, column2> matching values, then load that data as a table into your DBMS and apply the join operation.

Comment: I, infact, gave you this same advice in your recent [almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75093748/run-around-2000-update-statements-to-update-a-column-value-for-all-users).

Comment: If i have any other application to pass the value, i can pass these 3000 rows as table value parameter. But unfortunately i dont have any system. I have the database and  i can do the script release to  update the existing table to update these 3000 rows with the new column1 value.

Comment: Then you can `DECLARE` you table variable, `INSERT` your 3,000 rows, and then `UPDATE` your table using that variable. Which would result in 3 statements.

Comment: Or, alternatively, if you're building your script using undisclosed process, you could have it build a `VALUES` table construct you could `JOIN` to.

Comment: @Larnu I have updated with your suggested solution. Can you please confirm if this is fine? Thanks

Comment: @Larnu Usingi 3000 insert makes the query very slow.

Comment: A single `INSERT` followed by a single `UPDATE` will be faster than 3,000 seperate `UPDATE` statements, @MukilDeepthi .

Comment: What you need to do is upload this Excel sheet to SQL Server as a staging table. You can do this using the [Import/Export Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#wiz) in SSMS, as well as other tools. Then you can do a joined update from that

Comment: I manually generate the update statement  - so there must be some logic to what col1 is set to and which col2 values to apply them too, can that logic be applied to user using only user data in db  I wonder.

Answer (score 0):

I always find the Standard SQL way to update a join much more intuitive, and easier to test. eg

```
WITH Q AS
(
    SELECT U.PersionID, PE.PersonID PersonId_New
    FROM  [dbo].[User] U
    INNER JOIN #PersonEmail PE
        ON U.Email = PE.Email
)
--select * from Q
UPDATE Q SET PersionId = PersonId_New
```